# The child node "db_driver" at path "sonata_media" must be configured symfony

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I'm getting this error as I install the Sonata Media Bundle 2.3.0 in Symfony.

> The child node "db_driver" at path "sonata_media" must be configured.

and while using the further command,

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate --dest=src SonataMediaBundle
```

in CMD I'm getting error,

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
>    The child node "db_driver" at path "sonata_media" must be configured.

This is the image of my CMD where I'm getting the error

[image]

Here is image of my localhost where I'm getting problem

[image]

Please Help...!!!

Comment: The error message is pretty much self explanatory. Start by reading the documentation and make sure you have configure it correctly: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/3-x/doc/reference/installation.html

Comment: I'm not getting the thing that why this error is occurred. I'm installing sonata media bundle 2.3.0 and I'm continuously getting this error. Please elaborate!!

Comment: **_"Start by reading the documentation and make sure you have configure it correctly"_** - On the page I linked to, there's a description of what you need to configure. Follow those instructions.

Comment: I had checked and configured it correctly but still I'm getting the error.

**InvalidConfigurationException in ArrayNode.php line 235:
The child node "db_driver" at path "sonata_media" must be configured.**

Comment: "I had checked and configured it correctly" - I bet you did not. If you get this message, then your config.yml is invalid. Add it to your question.

Comment: Ok then tell me how can I work with config file?

Comment: I did not have sonata_media config at all where it had to be, and was getting that error. So maybe its your case also? I mean in my case it had to be in different yml file.